# Python 3 Using Regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need to look through a string and store the data in variables using I have to do it using regular expressions

This is an example of a string: I have to store the data for:

```
"www","7/27/2016","3:00pm",21.00,N/A,N/A,"12.90 - 21.75",N/A,+0.00,0,N/A
```

so far I can store the first symbol the date and time and the first number but I don't know how to go through the rest of the string and store the numbers

```
symb = re.match(r'"(.*?)"', line) #line is the line of string

if symb is not None:
    print(symb.group(1))
    print()

else:
    print("No Match")
    print()

date = re.match(r'".+?(\d+/\d+/\d+)"', line)

if date is not None:
    print(date.group(1))
    print()

else:
    return print("No Match")
    print()

time = re.match(r'".+?(\d+:\d+[a-z]{2})"', line)

if time is not None:
    print(time.group(1))
    print()

else:
    print("No Match")
    print()

 #lastPrice = The first number after the time  
lastPrice = re.match(r'.+?(\d+\.\d{2}?),', line)

if lastPrice is not None:
    print(lastPrice.group(1))
    print()

else:
    print("No Match")
    print()
```

Comment: Split on the `,` (ie use `csv`) and analyze the parts afterwards! No need to fiddle with regular expressions here.

Comment: @MGI can you edit your question and include more details on what are you trying to do? Right now you can do what Jan suggested. Let know if it works for you or not.

Comment: Yea it would be easier with csv but I need to use regular expressions to go through the string and store the data values in variables

Comment: You can grab the values after splitting and store them into variables. You still haven't provided full context of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

text = '"www","7/27/2016","3:00pm",21.00,N/A,N/A,"12.90 - 21.75",N/A,+0.00,0,N/A'
regex = r'.*?,"(\d+/\d+/\d{4})","(\d+:\d{2}\w{2})",(\d+\.\d+),N/A,N/A,"(\d+\.\d+) - (\d+\.\d+)",N/A,(\+\d+\.\d+),0,N/A'
listofmatches = re.findall(regex, text)
```

Assuming you have more than one data. 
Otherwise just use `listofmatches[0]` for only the first data

```
for lines in listofmatches:
    date, time, price, a, b, c = lines
    # do something with variables
```

or replace the `re.findall` with `re.search`

```
listofmatches = re.search(regex, text)
date, time, price, a, b, c = listofmatches.groups()
print(date)
```